# How do I use a NavigationLink in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

[image: Here is my Code]I am new to Xcode and work on a Login Page.
I try to link all pages with each other but even if I saw these Code in a tutorial working it doesn't work for me.

I hope you can help me, I would appreciate it a lot?

Comment: In your ext you hide the navigation link under white color si it can not be visible. I suppose you want a vstack somewhere. ZStack will put all contained view the last ones over the first ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NavigationLink the order of parameters is very important

here is an example that may help you

```
struct Page1: View {
    @Binding var GoToPage2: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button("Go To Page"){
                GoToPage2 = true
                print(GoToPage2)
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Page2(), isActive: $GoToPage2){
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Page 1")
    }
}

struct Page2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("page 2!")
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Page 2")
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var GoToPage2 = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: Page1(GoToPage2: $GoToPage2)){
                    Text("Signe In")
                        .padding()
                        .background(.regularMaterial)
                        .colorScheme(.dark)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("App")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding an EmptyView to a NavigationLink, and you don’t need isActive in his case and the button is completely useless.

Comment: EmptyView and isActive are required to access page 2.
Granted, we could just use that NavigationLink instead, but the question was how we achieve navigation with EmptyView and isActive.
And the button was just one example.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NavigationLink` in many different ways. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var active: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                    Label("Badge", systemImage: "app.badge")
                }
                NavigationLink("General", destination: EmptyView())
                NavigationLink("About", destination: EmptyView(), isActive: $active)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("View1")
    // put the second view in destination in which you want to reach
   // click in view2, this code will redirect from view1 to view2
                    NavigationLink(destination: View2()){
                        Text("View2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```