# SwiftUI - Dismissing a view, app goes back to content view instead of last view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have 3 views within my app where clicking on a button on each view opens a new view. When button is clicked on 3rd view, I wish to dismiss 3rd view and 2nd view should appear. However I am noticing that app navigates back to first view instead of 2nd view.

Note: I have lots of elements, hence lots of code in my app. I removed all of them and adding minimal working code here with which I am still able to repro the problem.

```
// *** Main App***

@main
struct sample_sampleApp: App {
    var body: some SwiftUI.Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView().ignoresSafeArea()
            }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
    }
}


// *** Content View or First View***

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var goToView2 = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: View2(), isActive: $goToView2) {
                Button(action: { goToView2.toggle() }) {
                    Text("This is first view - Click to go to View 2").foregroundColor(.red).font(.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// *** View2 View***

import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct View2: View {    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: View2ViewModel = View2ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .showView2:
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Button(action: { viewModel.navigateToView3() } ) {
                        Text("Second View - Click to go to View 3").foregroundColor(.blue).font(.title)
                    }
                }
            case .showView3:
                View3()
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            viewModel.isViewVisible = true
            viewModel.doSomething()
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            viewModel.isViewVisible = false
        }
    }
}

// *** View model for view 2***

class View2ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum View2AppState {
        case showView2
        case showView3
    }
    
    // UI changes when state gets updated.
    @Published var state: View2AppState = .showView2
    var isViewVisible = false
    
    func doSomething() {
        self.state = .showView2
    }
    
    func navigateToView3() {
        self.state = .showView3
    }
}

// *** View3***

struct View3: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: View3ViewModel = View3ViewModel()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .showView3:
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Button(action: { dismiss() } ) {
                        Text("Third View - Click to dismiss this and to go back to view 2").foregroundColor(.green).font(.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            viewModel.isViewVisible = true
            viewModel.doSomething()
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            viewModel.isViewVisible = false
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

// *** View model for view 3***

class View3ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum View3AppState {
        case showView3
    }
    
    // UI changes when state gets updated.
    @Published var state: View3AppState = .showView3
    var isViewVisible = false
    
    func doSomething() {
        self.state = .showView3
    }
}
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong. Sometime back I did use dismiss() while dismissing sheet and it worked fine, but not this this case. I am running this code on iOS 16.0, however my test app is set to iOS 15 as minimum version.

Edit: I tested on iOS 15.0 as well and was able to repro on it too, so something must be wrong with my code then. Not able to figure out what. I am using NavigationView in and navigation view style as Stack.

Comment: You use 2 @ObservedOvject  which are not linked to a StateObject in the ContentView. So you can not persist data between the different views.

Answer (score 1):

> When button is clicked on 3rd view, I wish to dismiss 3rd view and 2nd view should appear.

Let's first have a look at the code of `view2`.

```swift
struct View2: View {    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: View2ViewModel = View2ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .showView2:
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Button(action: { viewModel.navigateToView3() } ) {
                        Text("Second View - Click to go to View 3").foregroundColor(.blue).font(.title)
                    }
                }
            case .showView3:
                View3()
            }
        }
    }
}

//  here viewModel.navigateToView3() is just changing this state
//  func navigateToView3() {
//        self.state = .showView3
//    }
```

The current code behavior, when tapping to navigate to `view3`, replaces the content of `view2` with `view3` instead of actually navigating to it.

Therefore, when the `dismiss` function is called, it should not return to `view2` as it is **already in `view2`** displaying the content of `view3`.

So, going back to `view1` on the `dismiss` press is actually the correct behavior as per the code.

If you desire the outcome you are asking, consider modifying the code using a `closure` passed into the child view to change the state in `view2` or explore this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010446/how-do-i-use-a-navigationlink-in-swiftui) to actually navigate to it.

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing "showView3" state enum and adding a publisher property instead in view model. In View2, I removed "case .showView3" and instead added NavigationLink(destination: View3(), isActive: $viewModel.showView3, label: {}) outside of viewModel.state where "showView3" is a Publisher property in view model. Everything works fine with this change, however I would like to continue using state enum instead of adding multiple Publishers since I am trying to set a pattern. Any idea how can I do it using "case .showView3: { }" in View2?